# Guide / tutorial for design & analysis of experiments in retail settings

Tags: references, experiment-design

I want to develop my skill set in the design and analysis of experiments in retail, where we conduct experiments (introduction of new package, new product, discount, etc.) in test stores while maintaining the status quo in selected control stores. After the end of the experiment, we conduct analysis of sales to see if there is a lift in the data.

Does anyone know of any reading material about these concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question!

Though I think that you will find most books on the principles of experimental design helpful, here is an [HBR piece](https://hbr.org/2011/03/a-step-by-step-guide-to-smart-business-experiments) that serves as a step-by-step guide for business experiments.